# GetEnumerator error whilst running my script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to extract and export Azure Webapp settings using the below script

```
 $allWebApps = Get-AzureRmWebApp
 $resourceGroups = $allWebApps | Select-Object 'ResourceGroup' -Unique
 foreach($r in $resourceGroups)
{
$rgName = $r.ResourceGroup    
$webApps = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rgName

foreach($w in $webApps)
{
    $webAppName = $w.Name        
    Write-Host Processing Webapp : $webAppName

    $webApp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $webAppName
    $appSettings = $webApps.SiteConfig.AppSettings

    # Extract AppSettings to CSV
    $appSettings.GetEnumerator() | 
            Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending |
            Select-Object -Property @{n='Key';e={$_.Name}},Value |
            Export-Csv -Path "C:\Cloud\$webAppName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
}
```

but I keep getting the below error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Cloud\ExportsWebApp_config.ps1:17 char:9
+         $appSettings.GetEnumerator() |
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

can someone please assist?

Comment: that error usually means that the $Var in question is empty. have you checked to see if `$appSettings` contains anything at that point?

Answer (score -1):

```
$appSettings = $webApps.SiteConfig.AppSettings
```

I think this line should be changed, otherwise you're trying to get the properties of the entire array of web apps.

```
$appSettings = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not the issue, i was able to determine that